# How to know if input dialog is opened in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, junit, mockito, junit5

I am working on a project that tests Java programs using JUnit5. And in this case, I want to verify that when a button is clicked, it will really open an input dialog.

```
private void updateTextButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String newString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a string.");
}
```

The only way I can think of that the input dialog function has really been implemented is when I can simulate on my test that during button click, an input dialog has been opened.

So the test will be successful if an input dialog has been opened on button click, while failure if not.

**UPDATE:**

**The Mock function of JOptionPane:**

```
@Test
public void shouldShowInputDialogOnUpdateTextButtonClick() {
   try (MockedStatic<JOptionPane> jOptionPane = mockStatic(JOptionPane.class)) {
      // TODO: Check whether 'showInputDialog' has been called. But how?
   }

   updateTextButton = (JButton) TestUtils.getChildNamed(activity1, "updateTextButton");
   updateTextButton.doClick(); // Performs updateTextButtonActionPerformed() function
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to *not* open?

Comment: Why do you want to check if it's open? What does your test verify?

Comment: I want to check if the user has actually implemented that function when a button is clicked.

Comment: @DavidMaranga please [edit] your question to give a bit more context. For example include a case that should work and one that should fail.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca please check the updated question

Comment: @DavidMaranga you could mock `JOptionPane` and check whether the `showInputDialog` method has been called.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I've successfully mocked JOptionPane already. How do I know if the `showInputDialog` method has been called?

Comment: @DavidMaranga assuming you're using mockito, see [the docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4)